# Alphabetically sort array by sub-array's first element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm looking for a way to sort an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(
     [0] => array('a', '1', '2', '3', '4,' test'),
     [1] => array('c', '1', '2', '3', '5', 'test'),
     [2] => array('b', '1', '3', '4,' 5,', 'test),
);
```

so that it sorts the sub-array's according to the sub-array's first element, such that it returns:

```
$array = array(
     [0] => array('a', '1', '2', '3', '4,' test'),
     [1] => array('b', '1', '3', '4,' 5,', 'test),
     [2] => array('c', '1', '2', '3', '5', 'test'),
);
```

Does anyone have a good way about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `usort` function. Tons of examples are everywhere

Comment: _Does anyone have a good way about doing this?_ What ways have you tried o far?

Comment: Refactor the parent array as an associative array, where each key is the 0th element of each subarray, and the value is the subarray. Then use ksort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$array = array(
     0 => array('a', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'test'),
     1 => array('c', '1', '2', '3', '5', 'test'),
     2 => array('b', '1', '3', '4', '5', 'test'),
);

array_multisort(array_column($array, 1), SORT_ASC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 5
            [5] => test
        )

)
```

https://eval.in/633355

Comment: _Why is 3 arg in array_multisort an array? Dont get it?_ Thing i got it, reading documentations is usefull :)

Comment: `array_multisort(array_column($array, 0), SORT_ASC, $array);`

the index needs to be "0" if you want it sorted by the first element

Answer (score 2):

usort is what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

**For PHP 7:**

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] <=> $b['order'];
});
```

**PHP 5.3 or ++**

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

**PHP 5.2 or earlier**

```
function mySort($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}

usort($myArray, 'mySort');
```

**EDIT:** mySort instead of 'sort' from @Don't Panic 's comments. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Indeed use `usort()` [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php)

```
$array = array(
        array('a', '1', '2', '3', '4','test'),
        array('c', '1', '2', '3', '5', 'test'),
        array('b', '1', '3', '4','5','test'));

usort($array, function ($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a[0] == $b[0]) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
        });

var_dump($array);
```